# I am having problem writing a function. (vowels_repeated) return a string with only vowels being repeated

Tags: python, for-loop

The function is vowels_repeated which repeats all the vowels in the string.

```
def vowels_repeated(text: str, repeat: int) -> str:
    new = ''
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    for ch in text:
        if ch in vowels:
            new = text.replace(ch, ch*repeat)
    return new
```

`vowels_repeated('My name is Jack', 2)` should return `My naamee iis Jaack`

This code is not working, It gives me an empty string and I can't understand why.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
def vowels_repeated(text: str, repeat: int) -> str:
    new = ''
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    for ch in text:
        if ch not in vowels:
            new += ch
        else:
            new += ch * repeat
    return new

print(vowels_repeated('my name is jack', 2))
#output: my naamee iis jaack
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not optimal, you can replace your for loop through the string with a for loop through your vowels list. `str.replace` already loops through the string:

```
def vowels_repeated(text: str, repeat: int) -> str:
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    for v in vowels:
        text = text.replace(v, v*repeat)
    return text
```

Alternatively, you can not use replace and do things manually:

```
def vowels_repeated(text: str, repeat: int) -> str:
    out = ""
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    for c in text:
        if c in vowels:
            out += c * repeat
        else:
            out += c
    return out
```